What sort of load is this called? And will a 6mm bolt be sufficient?
Issue - I need to lift a 400kg object a few centimetres off the ground for a few minutes to find the centre of gravity (I think that's what it's called).
There are several horizontal holes though which a bolt can be slid and be attachment point for the hook or strap coming from a hoist (centre of object is hollow and open at top per photo). However these holes are only 6mm in diametre and I can only use one of these at a time.
Is such a load correctly described as shear? And will a high tensile 6mm bolt be sufficiently robust?
Thank you


use a fulcrum, such as a round rod

There are tables staring the load that can be applied to bolts and threads. Worth looking for.

shear is a side load.  A 6mm bolt is probbly not enough to support 400kg.  Why can't you use rigging straps?

Thank you all for your comments. It's a lifting keel on a boat. I need to find the centre of gravity so that the lifting mechanism is correctly located. The bolt is only a temporary attachment point whilst the centre of gravity ios being located.  There's minimal load on the threads as the bolt will be horizontal.
